# Getting junk character in C structure after parsing

Tags: c, xml

I am using a simple xml file.

```
<COMPANY>
    <EMPLOYEES>
            <EMPLOYEE>
                <NAME>BOB</NAME>
                <EMPID>51211</EMPID>
                <SEX>M</SEX>
                <DOB>10-1-1982</DOB>
                <DOJ>12-7-2001</DOJ>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </EMPLOYEES>
</COMPANY>
```

The xml booster meta definition file for the same is as below

```
    <SYSTEM NAME="testmeta" >
    <CCONFIG MAXLEN="100"
       ARRAYSIZE="5"
       FLATMODE="TRUE"/>        
    <ELEMENT NAME="COMPANY" TAG="COMPANY" MAIN="TRUE" >
            <FIELDS>
                    <FIELD NAME="EMPLOYEES" REFTYPE="EMPLOYEE" MODE="DEFAULT" />
            </FIELDS>
            <FORMULA>
                    <ENCLOSED NAME="EMPLOYEES" >
                            <META NAME="COMMENT" >Target field is EMPLOYEES</META>
                            <REPEAT TARGET="EMPLOYEES" ATLEASTONE="TRUE" >
                                    <ELEMENTREF NAME="EMPLOYEE" />
                            </REPEAT>
                    </ENCLOSED>
            </FORMULA>
    </ELEMENT>
    <ELEMENT NAME="EMPLOYEE" TAG="EMPLOYEE" >
            <FIELDS>
                    <FIELD NAME="NAME" TYPE="STRING" />
                    <FIELD NAME="EMPID" TYPE="INTEGER" />
                    <FIELD NAME="SEX" TYPE="STRING" />
                    <FIELD NAME="DOB" TYPE="STRING" />
                    <FIELD NAME="DOJ" TYPE="STRING" />
            </FIELDS>
            <FORMULA>
                    <CONCAT>
                            <ENCLOSED NAME="NAME" >
                                    <META NAME="COMMENT" >Target field is NAME</META>
                                    <PCDATA TARGET="NAME" />
                            </ENCLOSED>
                            <ENCLOSED NAME="EMPID" >
                                    <META NAME="COMMENT" >Target field is EMPID</META>
                                    <PCDATA TARGET="EMPID" />
                            </ENCLOSED>
                            <ENCLOSED NAME="SEX" >
                                    <META NAME="COMMENT" >Target field is SEX</META>
                                    <PCDATA TARGET="SEX" />
                            </ENCLOSED>
                            <ENCLOSED NAME="DOB" >
                                    <META NAME="COMMENT" >Target field is DOB</META>
                                    <PCDATA TARGET="DOB" />
                            </ENCLOSED>
                            <ENCLOSED NAME="DOJ" >
                                    <META NAME="COMMENT" >Target field is DOJ</META>
                                    <PCDATA TARGET="DOJ" />
                            </ENCLOSED>
                    </CONCAT>
            </FORMULA>
    </ELEMENT>
</SYSTEM>
```

Generated a .c and .h file for the same using xmlbooster lite using following command

```
xmlblit.exe -C testmeta.xmlb
```

Now in my application in `main` function i m calling  `accept_COMPANY` function and passing `S_XMLB_CONTEXT` context object. Function succeeds but when i print each employee value using

```
    printf("%s, %d, %s, %s, %s", En->aNAME,
    En->aEMPID,
    En->aSEX,
    En->aDOB,
    En->aDOJ);
    printf("\n");
```

i am getting junk characters printed, even for the integer `aEMPID` value.

I am using Visual studio 2010 to compile and run the C program.

Tried both Unicode and MultiByte project but no luck in getting the correct values.

I am getting output as

```
    UOB, 78, M, j0-1-1982, 1t-7-2001
```

After debugging the generated .c file found that, the generator is setting unwanted values for `PCDATA` type field. For e.g. for `NAME` field after retrieving the name from XML, the code has the following statement

```
/* Regexp */
if (strlen(obj->aNAME) > 0)
    (obj->aNAME)[0] = 'U';
```

Anyone faced similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote to xmlbooster support got the following reply.

> XMLBooster Lite only support Java ; C is only provided for evaluation purposes, as values are scrambled as you’ve noticed in your sample programs and in the generated code. You need to purchase XMLBooster Pro to generate production-level parsers in C.

Got the answer, hope this helps others too who are experimenting.